# Soap request and parse responce

Tags: soap, httprequest

I have URL which returns XML with session id when I run it from the browser.
http://11.111.111.11/scripts/webcrf.promasys/webui/dtp.p?name=login&userid=XXX&password=XXX&language=en

In Anonymous window i run

```
String xx = '?name=login&userid=XXX&password=XXX&language=en';
HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
req.setEndpoint('http://11.111.111.11/scripts/XXX/XXX/srs.k');
req.setMethod('POST');
req.setBody(String.valueOf(xx));
req.setTimeout(120000);
req.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/xml');
Http http = new Http();
HttpResponse res = http.send(req);
System.debug(res);
```

And get System.HttpResponse[Status=Service Unavailable, StatusCode=503]

How I can process this and pars from the response session id.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Ideally, you should just use [wsdl2apex](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_callouts_wsdl2apex.htm) to generate the appropriate methods for logging in. I think you're getting the 503 error because you're using a query string to try and log in, when you probably need a SOAP body instead. If you're not getting a 200 response from the server, then you haven't logged in successfully.

Parsing a SOAP response is a complicated affair. If, for some reason, you can't use the wsdl2apex tool from above, you'd have to parse the XML yourself. You can do this with [Dom.Document](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexref.meta/apexref/apex_classes_xml_dom_document.htm) class. Without knowing what the response looks like, there is no way we can provide you with the exact code you need. However, on our site, we do have some examples of parsing XML, so feel free to do a [search](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/search).

Comment: Thank you! @sfdcfox Do I need WSDL from the customer or I could generate it from this
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xmlreq>
</xmlreq>

Comment: @sartynallid You'll need a wsdl from your customer.

Comment: customer don't have WSDL :( Is it could be true? IF yes I streel couldn't connect based on a modified request

Comment: @sartynallid Without a wsdl, the service would be hard to use. Are you sure it's a SOAP service? It doesn't sound like it from the description you gave so far. Without knowledge of the service you're trying to access specifically, there's not much more we can do to help you.

Comment: 100 SOAP but with out WSDL file. Is it real?

Comment: @sartynallid 100 is a "continue" directive. That's not standard SOAP as far as I'm aware. Whatever they're doing is (best guess) some somebrew job. Do they at least have documentation on this? You're not going to be able to use this technique outside of a browser.